# conditional compilation in F#: something like #elif

Tags: f#

I'm trying to find a directive like #elif in C#. Does it exist? I can't find it anywhere. Sometimes there is need in several variants for the same symbol.

Comment: It does not exist.

Comment: Can you gives examples of what you mean by `Sometimes there is need in several variants for the same symbol.`

Comment: @Guy Coder For example: I'd like to have 'write' function to write in file log or to udp logger depending of two conditional compilation constants, say UDPLOG and FILELOG

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this during compilation? If your example is the only use case, that is usually done as runtime configuration of logging library, see for example https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Targets or https://logary.github.io/targets/overview/

Comment: @Honza Brestan C# programmers also could use your advice but they nevertheless have #elif possibility

Comment: What about  [#if and #else](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-directives)?

Comment: For this case just `#if` .. `#endif` should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to find a directive like #elif in C#. Does it exist?

No

What would be better would be to port the OCaml preprocessor [Camlp5](https://camlp5.github.io/) to F#. It not only has the directives as [macros](https://camlp5.github.io/doc/htmlc/macros.html) but a whole lot more, see [documentation](https://camlp5.github.io/doc/htmlc/).

OCaml was ported to Microsoft .NET then massaged into F#. So most any OCaml code translates almost line for line into F#. However there are some parts of OCaml, especially the meta stuff, that don't translate directly into F# and workarounds have to be done.